# A few vectors of same size. Given element in one of the vectors, fast access to corresponding elements in the other vectors

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<std::string> vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4;
//populate all vectors, all have the same size
//vec1 has different values
```

Now given some "key" in vec1, such as "foo", how do I quickly get the corresponding strings from the other vectors?

I will have to do this many times, with different keys in vec1, so this operation has to be fast.

Should I create a map that maps the elements in vec1 into index values (0,1,2,3,4...)?

How is this best done in C++?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: if `vec1 = {"bar", "foo"}` and `vec2 = {"Jack", "Jill"}` then "foo" and "Jill" are a match?

Comment: If vec2/3/4/etc can't be turned into 1 value in a map (struct of 4 strings, or a tuple of 4 strings) I would do like you suggested and make a map of the strings in vec1 to index values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "quickly".

If you care about **complexity** of retrieval by value, I would suggest to consider using an associative container such as `std::unordered_set` (constant lookup and insertion/removal time), or `std::set` and `std::multiset` (logarithmic lookup and insertion/removal time, the second one with duplicates allowed) instead of a `vector`.

However, it must be said that `vector`s allocate a contiguous region of memory to store their elements, so linear access will result in a high cache hit rate: thus, even though the complexity is worse, access is still "fast" in general, and you can use regular STL algorithms such as `std::find` or `std::find_if()` to find elements that match a given value or satisfy a given predicate.

Often, locality of the data can compensate for a worse complexity. The key here is to always do repeated **measurements** to determine what's the solution which gives you the best performance.

That said, the optimal solution is likely to depend on your **overall workload**: are you doing element-by-element iterations of your vectors at all? How often do you need to retrieve your elements *by position*? If those are not frequent operations, you might not need a vector. Moreover, how often are those vectors updated? How often do you need to lookup an element in those vectors *by value*? Your question does not say much about this.

If memory overhead is not an issue for you, you can certainly consider building a separate map as an index, and maintain redundant structures. If your `vector`s will be frequently updated with insertions and deletions, however, ensuring the consistency of the index and the `vector`s might become troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you really want is a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>>`. This would save you having to maintain the invariant that the `std::vector`s must be the same length. It will also give you **constant time** lookup of the other strings. For example,

```
typedef std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> value_type;
std::unordered_map<std::string, value_type> map;

// Populate the map
map["foo"] = std::make_tuple("first", "second", "third");
// ...

std::get<0>(map["foo"]); // Get the first string that "foo" maps to
```

If you really don't want to change the design from using four `std::vector`s, then you should use `std::find` and `std::distance` to find the index of `"foo"` in the first `std::vector` and then use that index on the others:

```
auto key_it = std::find(std::begin(vec1), std::end(vec1), "foo");
int index = std::distance(std::begin(vec1), key_it);
std::string s2 = vec2[index];
std::string s3 = vec3[index];
std::string s4 = vec4[index];
```